# About unix signals: sigsuspend() and race condition

Tags: c, unix, signals, race-condition

This is the coursework of my class. I'm not sure whether my answer is correct or not. Can someone give me any instruction. In the first question, I can't figure out why there is a race condition, is my explanation wrong?

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

void sigHandler(int signo) {
    /* Line C */
}

int main() {
    pid_t pid;
    sigset_t newmask, waitmask, oldmask;

    if ((pid = fork()) == 0) {      // Child
        struct sigaction action;

        sigemptyset(&newmask);
        sigemptyset(&waitmask);
        sigaddset(&newmask, SIGUSR1);
        sigaddset(&waitmask, SIGUSR2);
        sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &newmask, &oldmask);

        action.sa_flags = 0;
        sigemptyset(&action.sa_mask);
        action.sa_handler = sigHandler;
        sigaction(SIGUSR2, &action, NULL);
        sigaction(SIGINT, &action, NULL);
        sigaddset(&action.sa_mask, SIGINT);
        sigaction(SIGUSR1, &action, NULL);

        /* Line A: critical section */
        sigsuspend(&waitmask);  /* Line B */

    } else {        // Parent
        int stat;
        kill(pid, SIGUSR1);
        kill(pid, SIGUSR2);
        kill(pid, SIGINT);
        pid = wait(&stat);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

1. Although `sigsuspend()` is used here, there is still a race condition. Why?

Since we don't know when the parent process executes first or the child process. If the parent executes first, the parent sends `SIGUSR1`, `SIGUSR2` and `SIGINT` to the child, since `SIGUSR1` is now blocked, the `SIGUSR2` and `SIGINT` will be correctly catched, but we then `sigaddset(&action.sa_mask, SIGINT)`, which means the following line `sigaction(SIGUSR1, &action, NULL)` will blocked both `SIGUSR1` and `SIGINT`. Finally, the Line B calls `sigsuspend(&waitmask)`, which will wait signals excepts `SIGUSR2`. But here is my question: since `sigsuspend(&waitmask)` didn't block `SIGUSR1`, why there is still a race condition? Were the `SIGUSR2` and `SIGINT` catched already?

2. Suppose the child process receives (a)`SIGUSR2` at line A, (b)`SIGINT` when blocked at line B, and (c)`SIGUSR1` when `SIGINT` is caught at line C, how the child process' signal mask changes? Explain your answer.

(a) The mask contains `SIGUSR1` (by `sigprocmask()`) and `SIGINT`(by `sigaddset()`).

(b) The mask contains only `SIGUSR2` (by `sigsuspend()`).
After `sigsuspend()`, the mask restore to `SIGUSR1` and `SIGINT`.

(c) The mask contains `SIGINT` and `SIGUSR1`, so it'll block `SIGUSR1`.

3. Suppose the child process receives (a)`SIGUSR1` at line A, (b)`SIGUSR2` when blocked at line B, and (c)`SIGINT` when `SIGUSR1` is caught at line C, how the child process' signal mask changes? Explain your answer.

(a) The mask contains both `SIGUSR1` (by `sigprocmask()`) and `SIGINT` (by `sigaddset()`) and the `SIGUSR1` is blocked.

(b) The mask contains only `SIGUSR2`(by `sigsuspend()`).
   After `sigsuspend()`, the mask restore to `SIGUSR1` and `SIGINT`.

(c) The mask contains `SIGINT` and `SIGUSR1`, so it'll block `SIGINT`.